# How do I get emacs to start in Vi mode?

Tags: vim, emacs

I've tried putting `(setq term-setup-hook 'vip-mode)` in my .emacs file but this only seems to load the vip module and I have to manually call `vip-change-mode-to-vi` and C-z doesn't work as an alias for that method.

What am I doing wrong here?

p.s. Please spare me any religious sentiments.

Comment: Are you trying to cause some sort of explosion or something? :)

Comment: nope, I'm just a long time Vim user who likes the emacs/gdb integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question, really: you need to call `vip-change-mode-to-vi`.  EMACS is just a lisp interpreter with some glossy side-effects; if you want to always be in vip vi mode, call the function.

A couple things:

1. You should use `add-hook`.  What you're using will remove any other hooks.

   (add-hook 'term-setup-hook ...)
2. Consider using a lambda expression to stick things together, as

   (add-hook 'term-setup-hook (lambda () (vip-mode)))

   That means you have one closure that you can put all this stuff into

Comment: How do I call the function? I tried (vip-change-mode-to-vi) but it tells me that `Symbol's function definition is void`. I guess it need to wait for the module to load or something.

Comment: I happen to be on the one computer I won wih no emacs, but yeah, that indicates something isn't loaded.  There are a couple options: you need to `require` something, or vip-mode is an autoloaded package.  Get into the scratch buffer in a clean EMACS, and enter `(require vip-mode)` followed by C-j to execute it, and see what happens.  It ikf returns `t`, then add that require to your ,emacs.

Answer (score 1):

```
 (setq viper-mode t)
 (require 'viper)
```

Answer (score 1):

If really want to use `vi/vim` in `Emacs`, I think you maybe like evil(a great vim emulation, the successor to Vimpulse and vim-mode).

If you want to know more about evil, you can Google `Emacs wiki evil`.

Basic description: (after you have installed this package)
With basic settings, this package will get in vim-mode at start up (also, you can change it).

You can use C-z to vim-mode, in this mode, you will also have other vim modes (normal insert visual ...), if you want to leave vim-mode to emacs mode, type C-z again.

Evil, really evil & cool!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get emacs started in `vip-mode` by doing what I found [here](http://billharlan.com/pub/emacs/). If you scroll to the bottom, there's a link to a [.emacs](http://billharlan.com/pub/emacs/.emacs) file, and I copied the first three commands from there:

```
(setq term-setup-hook 'vip-mode)
(global-unset-key "\e\e")
(put 'eval-expression 'disabled nil)
```

I also saw an entry elsewhere from someone who just added to their `.emacs`:

```
(vip-mode)
```

I tried that, but the first time I started emacs with it, it prompted me with an "inhibit vip-mode something", to which I responded `n`, and after that, subsequent startups wouldn't use `vip-mode`.